# I want to Join two tables each related (by a ForeignKey) to a third one (but not each other)

Tags: django-models, join, foreign-keys

The three models relevant to this question are:

```
class MaterialList(models.Model):
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organizations, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, blank=True)
    Material = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    PartType = models.ForeignKey(WhsePartTypes, null=True, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    Price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    PriceUnit = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    TypicalContainerQty = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    TypicalPalletQty = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Notes = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

    UniqueConstraint('org', 'Material')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['org','Material']


class CountSchedule(models.Model):
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organizations, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, blank=True)
    CountDate = models.DateField(null=False)
    Material = models.ForeignKey(MaterialList, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    Counter = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    Priority = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    ReasonScheduled = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    Notes = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)

    UniqueConstraint('org', 'CountDate', 'Material')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['org','CountDate', 'Material']


class ActualCounts(models.Model):
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organizations, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, blank=False)
    CountDate = models.DateField(null=False)
    CycCtID = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    Material = models.ForeignKey(MaterialList, on_delete=models.RESTRICT)
    Counter = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
    LocationOnly = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    CTD_QTY_Expr = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    BLDG = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    LOCATION = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    PKGID_Desc = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    TAGQTY = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    FLAG_PossiblyNotRecieved = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    FLAG_MovementDuringCount = models.BooleanField(blank=True, default=False)
    Notes = models.CharField(max_length = 250, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['org', 'CountDate', 'Material']
```

These models arise from a migration from a non-Python system to a Python-Django driven system.  Most of the time, I only need the forward relations CountSchedule.Material and ActualCounts.Material.  There is one report my bosses *L_O_V_E*, however.  This report joins ActualCounts and CountSchedule where ActualCounts.CountDate=CountSchedule.CountDate and ActualCounts.Material=CountSchedule.Material.  (Actually, the report has 3 sections, which boil down to a LEFT JOIN, a RIGHT JOIN and an INNER JOIN.  For now, I just need help with any of these as a start).

For the moment, I'm going with raw SQL, but I'd like to know if the ORM has a solution.

Any advice?

I've already tried

```
    M = MaterialList.objects.select_related('actualcounts_set', 'countschedule_set').filter(org=_userorg, actualcounts__CountDate=datestr, countschedule__CountDate=datestr)
```

which resulted in

> Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'countschedule_set', 'actualcounts_set'. Choices are: org, PartType

Comment: use prefetch_related instead of select_related.

Comment: That's it!!  Since it worked I also reread the docs and saw that this is by design: select_related is limited to single-valued relationships - foreign key and one-to-one, while  prefetch_related  can prefetch many-to-many and many-to-one objects, which cannot be done using select_related.

I'm still a little stuck on the outer joins, but I think  reading the docs more carefully and a little experimentation will get me there.  Thanks!!